# How to get socket.io handshake query in Go

Tags: go, socket.io

We use the [`go-socket.io` package](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io) to run a socket server and we need to authenticate users with handshake query data.
In `node.js` we used code like:

```
authDataString = socket.handshake.query.authData;
```

and we need to do something similar in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Request` field of a [`socket`](https://godoc.org/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io#Socket) to get query parameters from the request URL using [`FormValue`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.FormValue):

```
    log.Print(socket.Request().FormValue("foo"))
```